# Update related (lookup) record when lead is converted

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

I attempted to use the Lead.IsConverted flag to update a checkbox on a related record in the `after update` context however it does not appear that converting the lead activates the trigger code:

```
    if (trigger.isUpdate){
        Date oldFollowUpDate = trigger.oldMap.get(lead.id).Follow_Up_Date__c;
        Date newFollowUpDate = trigger.newMap.get(lead.id).Follow_Up_Date__c;

        if (oldFollowUpDate != newFollowUpDate || lead.IsConverted){
            comp.Id = existingCompanies.get(lead.rWeb_Domain__c).Id;
            comp.Follow_Up_Date_Changed__c = true;
        }
    }

        //Add companies to upsert
        companyUpsert.add(comp);
    }
```

If I remove the IsConverted condition the trigger will properly run when the field `Follow_Up_Date__c` is changed. That act is what I want to replicate when the lead is converted but adding the condition does not appear to work.

Searching google for "Lead trigger activation" is really only giving me advice on creating triggers that automatically convert leads for me which is not what I am looking for.

Is it possible converting a lead does not count as an update on the lead?

Comment: Triggers do fire during conversion. I suspect your logic flaw lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I see that you're grabbing the newFollowUpDate value from Trigger.newMap instead of reading it directly from the lead variable, but then reading the IsConverted flag directly from that same variable. What actually defines the variable called "lead" here? If you drop System.debug statements to check the IsConverted flag in both your lead variable and in your Trigger.newMap, are they as you would expect them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much trial and error, I found the solution which seems obvious in retrospect.

I simply added an `IF()` block to the `before update` context that sets `Follow_Up_Date__c` to null if `IsConverted` is true. This in turns uses my existing trigger logic to flag `Follow_Up_Date_Changed__c`.

Answer (score 1):

See the `Apex Developer Guide`:

> ## [Operations That Don't Invoke Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm)
>
> The before triggers associated with the following operations are fired during lead conversion only if validation and triggers for lead conversion are enabled in the organization:
>
> - insert of accounts, contacts, and opportunities
> - update of accounts and contacts

Navigate to `Setup` > `Customize` > `Leads` > `Lead Settings` and make sure the `Require Validation for Converted Leads` setting is true.

[image: Require Validation for Converted Leads]

Comment: That snippet mentions the before context; will my code in the after context still run?

Comment: @JaredT It should affect all triggers. The help text certainly implies as much.

Comment: Confirmed the 'Require Validation` box was checked and the errant behavior persisted (apparently the box was already checked)